# How do I change the child of inflate viewgroup

Tags: java, android

I want to change the child of the inflate viewgroup
i don't know how to access widget

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ScrollView activitymain;
LinearLayout rootLayout, subInfo;
TextView tvSerName, tvSerPrice, tvStarDate, tvNextDate;
CreateSubActivity createSubActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    subInfo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subinfo);
    activitymain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    tvSerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSerName);   //these are child of subinfo
    tvSerPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSerPrice);
    tvStarDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStarDate);
    tvNextDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNextDate);

}
```

This method works when a button is pressed in another activity.
When the view is added, I want to change the text of tvSerName, tvSerPrice, tvStarDate, tvNextDate through setText(), but it does not work.
What should I do

```
void addView() {
    createSubActivity = new CreateSubActivity();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup addview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.subinfo, null);
    tvSerName.setText("name"); // it does not works

    rootLayout.addView(addview);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view you are trying to set text on has not be set from the viewGroup yet.

You still need to set `tvSerName = addview.findVieById(R.id.tvSerName);` before setting text on it.

```
void addView() {
    createSubActivity = new CreateSubActivity();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup addview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.subinfo, null);

    //here
    tvSerName = addview.findVieById(R.id.tvSerName);

    //then set its text
    tvSerName.setText("name"); // it does not works

    rootLayout.addView(addview);
}
```